# Provide a logical translation of "There are at least n objects" in $L_=$

Tags: logic, induction

Let $S_n$ stand for "There are at least n materials objects".

First I am asked, using the dictionary Q: ...is a material object, to provide a definition of $S_0$.
This seems like a non-question to me - surely it states nothing? I have considered something like
$\exists xQx\lor\lnot\exists xQx$ which is obviously a tautology. Do you think this is what they are looking for?

Past this it asks for me to specify (recursively or otherwise) to specify an $L_=$ sentence for $S_n$.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I agree with you; if we "equate" "There are at least $n$ objects" with $∃^{\ge n} x$, then we have that $S_0$ is $∃^{\ge 0} x$ which means: "either there are some object ($\exists x$) or there are none ($\lnot \exists x$)", which in turn is formalized as : $∃x ∨ ¬∃x$.

Comment: In the language I'm using there is no superscript on my $\exists$ so I have to do things a bit differently, but thank you.

Comment: They were only abbreviations; $∃^{≥1}x$ stands for the "usual" : $\exists x$ and $∃^{≥2}x$ for $\exists x \exists y (\ldots \land x \ne y)$, and so on.

Comment: Ah thank you, makes sense.

My recursive definition is starting to take form - I say that $S_0$ is as defined before, but I replace $x$ with $x_0$.

Then $S_n$ is defined as $S_n$$_-$$_1$ $\land$ $\exists x_n$$_-$$_1$ $Qx_n$$_-$$_1$ $\land$ $\bigcap^n$$^-$$^2$$_1$$\lnot$$x_i=x_n$$_-$$_1$